# Hyperref-ize the keywords in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

once I asked in [Insert key words & key phrases into toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19828/3954) whether it is possible to insert some keywords in the toc that it looks like this:

```
Contents

1 section .............................1

key word 1 - key phrase 2 - key word 3

    1.1 subsection ...............................5

    key word 1 - key phrase 2 - key word 3 -

    key word 4 - key phrase 5 - key word 6
```

egreg provided this answer which works perfectly well:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifsection
\newif\ifsubsection
\newtoks\keywordstoks
\preto\section{\flushkeywords\sectiontrue\subsectionfalse}
\preto\subsection{\flushkeywords\sectionfalse\subsectiontrue}
\preto\enddocument{\flushkeywords}

\newcommand{\flushkeywords}{%
    \ifsection\addtocontents{toc}{\formatkwsection{\protect\@gobble\the\keywordstoks\relax}}\fi
  \ifsubsection\addtocontents{toc}{\formatkwsubsection{\protect\@gobble\the\keywordstoks\relax}}\fi
  \keywordstoks={}}

\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\@bsphack\keywordstoks=\expandafter{\the\keywordstoks\kwsep#1} \@esphack}
\newrobustcmd{\kwsep}{~-- }
\newrobustcmd{\formatkwsection}[1]{#1\par\medskip}
\newrobustcmd{\formatkwsubsection}[1]{{\leftskip=2.2em\relax#1\par}\smallskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}

Abc \keyword{key1} def \keyword{key2}

\subsection{Subsection}

Ciao \keyword{key3} ciao \keyword{key4}

\subsection{Another}

x

\end{document}
```

Now my question: Is it possible to hyperref-ize the keywords?

Comment: It depends on what you want these hyperlinks do.

Comment: they should behave like the hyperlinked toc. If you press the cursor on the keyword in the toc, the document should "jump" to the corresponding position in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the definition of `\keyword` into

```
\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\@bsphack
  \keywordstoks=\expandafter{%
    \the\keywordstoks\kwsep\protect\hyperlink{keyword.#1}{#1}}%
  \hypertarget{keyword.#1}{}%
  \@esphack}
```