# How to add a description ("precis") to a toc entry with KOMA-Script class?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Using the KOMA-Script class I'ld like to add chapter descriptions to the table of contents to provide a short description of this chapter right in the TOC.

I've already found the "memoir" document class with the \chapterprecis{...} command, but this would make it impossible to use KOMA-Script, as it is a class, too.

The "tocloft" package provides a similar command, but forces to print the precis under the chapter title in the text with a quite bad positioning.

Is there any package around that works with KOMA-Script or a solution in the KOMA-Script class itself to provide this behaviour?

Comment: Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/table-of-contents-with-additional-description-of-entries) question help?

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19828/insert-key-words-key-phrases-into-toc), it's the same questions, and the answers only requite the `etoolbox` or `tocloft` packages

Comment: Thanks Tom (I've heard that name before *g*), the example was helpful! I skipped the command "\cftchapterprecistoc" when evaluating the tocloft package, only found "\cftchapterprecis".

Comment: Also thanks to lockstep. Sorry, I overlooked your answer, as I assumed your name to be some kind of a Stack Exchange function with the time my question will be locked for any unknown reason :-)

Comment: @Christoph Jüngling: You are a German so I think you will understand the post of Markus Kohm. He has a pacakge `screxperimental` which allows you to set the toc separately. The code is insert in `KOMA-Script` v3.10.
here the link: http://www.komascript.de/node/1231

Comment: "Some kind of function" -- that's a new one. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now use the "tocloft" package with its command `\cftchapterprecistoc{text}`.

Additionally I found a recommendation to create a similar command `\cftsectionprecistoc{text}`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cftsectionprecistoc}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{%
  {\leftskip \cftsecindent\relax
   \advance\leftskip \cftsecnumwidth\relax
   \rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
   \textit{#1}\protect\par}}}
\makeatother
```

This now works fine even that `\cftchapterprecis{text}` (without "toc" at the end!), which additionally writes the precis under the chapter heading itself, doesn't consider the correct distance between the lines.

Answer (score 5):

Something like

```
\newcommand{\chapterprecis}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \unexpanded{\unexpanded{{\small#1\par}}}}}
```

should work. One has to customize the appearance of the precis and, perhaps, make sure that there's no page break between the chapter and the precis:

```
\chapter{A title}
\chapterprecis{A precis}
```